# Method of defining an array - used to work php 5 not in php 7

Tags: php

My php code builds an array as follows:

```
$outputarraystl ="";
```

Then in a loop I add extra lines to array using:

```
$outputarraystl[] = array(
'id22_stl' => $rowstl['id22_stl'],
'st_id' => $rowstl['st_id'],
'prodserv_uid' => $rowstl['prodserv_uid'],
'qty' => $rowstl['qty'],
'item_amount' => number_format($rowstl['item_amount'], 2),                          
'stl_title' => $rowstl['stl_title'],
'stl_avail' => $rowstl['stl_avail']
```

);

This runs ok in PHP 5 but in PHP 7 it complains about the [] -

My question is - how should I be defining this array ?

Comment: Simply remove `$outputarraystl ="";`. There is no need to initialize it before you start adding elements to the array. It's complaining because you initialized it as a string then tried to use it as an array.

Comment: Well if he doesn't initialize the array variable before the loop, it's going to get reset every time it runs. Just change it to `$outputarraystl = array();` or `$outputarraystl = []`

Comment: Looks to raise a fatal error from Php version 7.1.0 not necessarily 7.  https://3v4l.org/8U1EQ

Comment: This is related to [*The empty index operator is not supported for strings anymore*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.empty-string-index-operator) backward incompatibilities in PHP 7.1 `Applying the empty index operator to a string (e.g. $str[] = $x) throws a fatal error instead.` and `Formerly, empty strings where silently treated like an empty array.` which is no longer the case in PHP 7.1.